# Sql Server optimizer trees: CONVERTED and TREE_COPIED_OUT

Tags: sql-server, optimization

Using the trace flags 8605, 8606, and 8607 in a Sql Server query, we can have a look at the logical trees that are built. Trying to associate each tree with the optimization phases of the First Step I've ended up with the following schema:

[image]

If the schema is correct, I have two questions then:

1. The Converted tree, shown using the TF 8605 is generated by the Parser or the Binder?
2. What is the TREE_COPIED_OUT listed with the other tree types as output of the following query?

select * from sys.dm_xe_map_values where name = 'query_optimizer_tree_id';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the schema is correct

I wouldn't lump all those into 'simplification', but it's your diagram. All such representations are arbitrarily abstract and incomplete anyway.

> 1. The Converted tree, shown using the TF 8605 is generated by the Parser or the Binder?

The *converted tree* is the *parse tree* from the parser, imported and transformed ('converted') into a tree structure that the early compilation stages find convenient to work with.

> 2. What is the TREE_COPIED_OUT listed with the other tree types as output of the following query?

`OUTPUT_TREE` is created from the memo after cost-based optimization. `TREE_COPIED_OUT` is after post-optimization rewrites (among other things). The tree is copied out from the query optimizer and used by the execution engine to build an executable plan. The parent extended event is for internal use and cannot be fired in consumer builds.